# Finding a good cover such that its lifting is still a good cover

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $Y$ be a compact manifold, $X$ a topological space and $f: X \to Y$ a surjective map. Suppose further that every point in $Y$ has arbitrarily small open neighbourhoods such that their preimages in $X$ are contractible.

Under these conditions, can we find a good cover for $Y$ such that its preimage is also a good cover for $X$ (i.e. such that any finite intersections of open sets in the cover is contractible)?

This would follow easily if the preimage of a contractible subspace in $Y$ was still contractible, but I have been unable to prove this or to find a counterexample.

Comment: I dont know why did exactly somebody give it a down vote?

Comment: @AnubhaV Probably because the question shows no sign of any effort on the OP's part.

Comment: Do you assume that the small open neighborhoods in $Y$ are contractible?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I probably can't assume that in the specific problem I am trying to solve. However, I would surely like to see a proof of this fact even with slightly stronger hypotheses